# How to render objects up to down on react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, components

So basically I have a list of objects like this:

const objects = [{name: 'some name', count: 'how many of that name'}, ...]

And I'm trying to render them like this:

```
        {objects.map((item) => (
            <Grid item key={item.name} xs={2} style={styles.count}>
                <Typography
                    key={item.name}
                    align="right"
                    component="h1">
                    {`${item.name}: ${item.count}`}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
        ))}
```

As you can imagine the result of this is something like this

```
name 1: 4   name 2: 4    name 3: 4
name 4: 4   name 4: 4
```

But I need something like this instead:

```
name 1: 4   name 3: 4    name 5: 4
name 2: 4   name 4: 4
```

Comment: Have a look at this : [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look through [React MUI Grid-auto-flow](https://mui.com/system/grid/#grid-auto-columns)

Align your code and add style to parent container like this:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: 'grid',
    gridAutoFlow: 'column',
    gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
    gap: 1,
  }}
>
  <Item>1</Item>
  <Item>2</Item>
  <Item>3</Item>
  <Item>4</Item>
  <Item>5</Item>
</Box>
```

end result shall be like this

[image: result]

Comment: your answer can be improved! It dosent work if length of item arrays changes. I edit your answer , please see [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-curie-j4yp8i?file=/src/App.js:123-124)

Comment: Great,  but it really depends on how many rows or columns user wants, if we want fixed 2 rows, then the answered code perfectly aligns all item automatically in 2 rows and columns will be calculated automatic as required.    
Number of fixed rows can be controlled by gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(   numberOfRowsFixed  , 1fr)',.. see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-grass-4chun7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your answer is good, I will use it from now on if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't `css` trick for your question. but i have a `js` trick and It may help you  :

```
const items = [
  { name: 1, count: 5 },
  { name: 2, count: 5 },
  { name: 3, count: 5 },
  { name: 4, count: 5 },
  { name: 5, count: 5 },
  { name: 6, count: 5 },
  { name: 7, count: 5 }
  ....
];

function getColumns() {
  //get window width;
  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(windowWidth);
  let columnsNumber = 3;

  //responsive on window width
  if (windowWidth < 400) {
    columnsNumber = 2;
  }

  const columns = new Array(columnsNumber);

  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    var columnNumber = Math.floor(index / columns.length);
    if (columns[columnNumber] === undefined) {
      columns[columnNumber] = [item];
    } else {
      columns[columnNumber].push(item);
    }
    console.log(columns);
  });
  return columns;
}

export default function App() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(getColumns());
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setColumns(getColumns());
    });
  }, []);
  if (!columns) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }

  console.log(columns);

  return (
    <Grid container>
      {columns.map((column, index) => (
        <Grid item key={index} xs={12/columns.length}>
          <Column items={column} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}

function Column({ items }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <Grid item key={item.name} xs={12}>
            <Typography key={item.name} align="right" component="h1">
              {`${item.name}: ${item.count}`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

result of code is :

[image]

You can see [domo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-dijkstra-xph1rn?file=/src/App.js:0-1758%5C)

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to use a `Grid` container with multiple rows 3 columns for each

```
import { Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const objects = [{name: 'some name', count: 'how many of that name'}, ...];

const rows = [];
let currentRow = [];
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  currentRow.push(objects[i]);
  if (currentRow.length === 3 || i === objects.length - 1) {
    rows.push(currentRow);
    currentRow = [];
  }
}

return (
  <Grid container spacing={2} direction="column">
    {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
      <Grid item container key={rowIndex} spacing={2} direction="row">
        {row.map((item, itemIndex) => (
          <Grid item key={itemIndex} xs={4} style={styles.count}>
            <Typography align="right" component="h1">
              {`${item.name}: ${item.count}`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
);
```